# Can't get user in template using django.contrib.auth

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

What am i doing wrong? I just want the username of the user. I am logged so i don't know why it's not working.

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def check_user(request):
    data = dict()
    user = User.objects.all()
    data['user'] = user
    return render(request, 'check_user.html', data)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^check_user/$', views.check_user, name='check_user'),
```

check_user.html

```
{{ request.user.is_authenticated }}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And i'm getting this:

```
CallableBool(True)

Welcome, new user. Please log in.
```

when i should get:

```
Welcome, admin. Thanks for logging in.
```

If i use: {% if request.user.is_authenticated %} instead of {% if user.is_authenticated %} i'm getting this:

```
Welcome, . Thanks for logging in.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your view, you don't need to create data['user']. Because in template, Django already pass the template variable `{{ user }}`.

So in your view remove this data dict, and keep the current context, without modification.

```
def check_user(request):
    return render(request, 'check_user.html', {})
```

And your template will work. (don't need to change something)

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please log in.</p>
{% endif %}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates

Comment: Ooooh so i don't need to pass User.objects.all() attall because it's automatically implemented in the template?

Comment: If you need the list of all your User, yes you need. But here you ask for the username of current user, who requested the page ? right ?

Comment: You have more information in documentation. About the RequestContext. :) Glad to help you. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

`user` is queryset object in your template, in other words it is list of users, not single user.
If you need current user use this:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ request.user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
```

instead of

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
```

**UPDATE**

As Wilfried said in his answer and comment, it is not good practice to override variable `user` in template. So if you need list of users in view it would be better to rename context variable to `users`:

```
users = User.objects.all()
data['users'] = users
```

Comment: I've used that but i forgot to write, if i use that i'm getting this: Welcome, . Thanks for logging in.

Comment: @NitaAlexandru did you also changed `<p>Welcome, {{ request.user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>` part?

Comment: it works but so does Wilfried's answer and it's simpler, thanks for the info

Comment: Not a good idea to override the template variable `{{ user }}` with a list of all user. If your view don't override this variable. `{{ request.user }}` is equal to `{{ user }}`. You need to correct your view, and used `{{ user }}` in your template like Django recommend it.